# gradient background for UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having trouble creating a simple gradient on a UITableView working with some consultant code.  When a button is clicked, a popover is presented.  In the popover, I have a navigationController, and its rootViewController is my custom class.  My class has these properties

```
@interface TargetDetailView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    CGGradientRef backgroundGradient;
    UITableView *_targetTableView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIGradientView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *TargetTableView;
```

in viewDidLoad, I do this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef gray = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    backgroundGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(gray, (CFArrayRef)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:70./255 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:35./255 alpha:1] CGColor], nil], nil);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(gray);
    [self.backgroundView setGradient:backgroundGradient];
```

My cells backgroundView are set to `[UIColor clearColor]`.  Also, my tableView in IB has its background set to `[UIColor clearColor]` as well.  When I present my popover however, I do not see the gradient.  In IB, the hierarchy is the class's .view property, then the backgroundView outlet, and the UITableView inside that view.

I have tried other things to troubleshoot, like getting rid of the gradientView completely, and putting the tableView as the only item in the class's .view property.  Then I just try self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

and I do not see any colors.  Everything looks to be gray.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is the code I used for gradient for a UILable , it is the same for all UIViews :

```
gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = lbl_change.bounds;

//Blue Color
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0x2B60DE) CGColor],    (id)[UIColorFromRGB(0x2554C7) CGColor], nil];

[lbl_change.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

I have added the gradient to Layer and also make sure that you have set the frame for your gradient.

Comment: Even though i give the index as zero (0) .. the sublayer appears at top .. what should i do .. ?

Comment: please put part of your code, there are many conditions could cause this

Comment: i did this to overcome the problem `UIView *tableBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [tableBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gLayer atIndex:1];
    [tableView setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundView];` .. now it works fine ;)

Comment: According to Apples docs, a subview is always obscuring the superview (the tableview in this case). I updated an existing app that worked fine with this to Xcode 9 and a newer iOS SDK and it broke - the gradient view I had applied as a subview suddenly always stay on top of the table view cells. Haven't figured out a workaround except for switching around so the tableview becomes a subview of the gradientview instead (which, I guess, is the logical solution...)